# What happens when the service returns START_STICKY

Tags: android, service

Suppose, my phone has lot of memory and a service is executed on event of something. It completes its task and returns `START_STICKY`. Will it continue to run in background because it returns `START_STICKY`.

My assumption is NO because `START_STICKY` is only considered if the service terminates on event of low memory and not in event of service completion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service continues running until [Context.stopService()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#stopService%28android.content.Intent%29) or [stopSelf()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#stopSelf%28int%29) is called.

Comment: I have a confusion. What do we mean by "continues running" here ? If I have a routine of code, what will happen after that is completely executed? Will it continue to execute again and again in a loop ?

Comment: @MadhurAhuja I am not so sure about that.But certainly your code will run only once.The service will stay there even If its not doing anything.I generally consider it is best practice to call stopSelf() once code execution finishes.